# Windows Sandbox, how to pass CTRL+ALT+DEL to the Sandbox?

Tags: remote-desktop, start-menu, sandbox, ctrl-alt-delete, windows-sandbox

Within a Windows Sandbox, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, it does not act on the Sandbox, *even* if I am in full-screen mode (this is on Windows 10). In fact, no system key combinations operate on the Sandbox and always go back to the Host system, so if I just press <kbd>WinKey</kbd> it will open the Host Start Menu and not that of the Windows Sandbox (again, *even* if the Sandbox is maximised in full-screen at the time).

Within a Remote Desktop session, we can of course press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to mimic a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, and if the Remote Desktop session is fully screen, then pressing <kbd>WinKey</kbd> will operate on the remote system, and Windows Sandbox does appear to use a Remote Desktop frame when it is in fullscreen mode.

How can we pass system keypresses like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>WinKey</kbd> to a Sandbox system instead of the Host system?

Comment: Why do you want CTRL+ALT+DEL and what do you suppose that it will do?

Comment: I know what CTRL+ALT+DEL does. That was just one of the 2 examples (the other being accessing the Start menu by pressing the WIN key). I can use CTRL+ALT+DEL to get to Task Manager for example. The point being: we should be able to access all of these keys, in the same way that we can in a full screen Remote Desktop, since that is using the same frame as a Sandbox.

Comment: The thing is that I am using Windows Sandbox a huge amount as it is very powerful and flexible container technology (that has sadly been down-played as if it is a toy). I'm benefitting a great deal from using it, though am hitting a few little issues like this (not just CTRL+ALT+DEL, but every system key combo). I've read this works in Win 11, just not in Win 10. That could be due to a new build of Sandbox (but unlikely as Microsoft have mentioned nothing) but could also be that a few registry keys can fix this (that's what I'm hoping).

Comment: @YorSubs - Keep in mind Super User is not a forum, I mention this fact, because of a comment you made to the now deleted answer.  Are you using Windows 10 or Windows 11?

Comment: I'm using Win 10. The frustrating thing is that system shortcut keys are respected in Remote Desktop sessions (Hyper-V and Sandbox share the same session frame as Sandbox as you can see when you full-screen a Sandbox session, and Hyper-V also respects system key combos in that mode) which indicates that it may well be fixable by a simple registry hack. Super User etc meets the definition of a forum, but I don't come here to chat, it's not that kind of forum of course; I come here for questions and to help others when I can. Super User is an amazing and valuable resource in that respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using alternate shortcuts for host keys,
Windows Sandbox is built more like the Remote Desktop.

I haven't found any official documentation for these alternate keys
for the Sandbox, so I used the third-party article
[Helpful keyboard shortcuts for working with "windowed" Remote Desktop](https://www.carehart.org/blog/2013/2/6/remote_desktop_keyboard_shortcuts).

I tested some of the shortcuts which worked :

- For triggering a Windows key (Start menu) : <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>
- Alt+Tab functionality :
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>

However,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>
did not do the equivalent of Ctrl+Alt+Delete.
The implementation for the Sandbox is only partial.

I have not tested the other possible keys.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks Harry. I found another combo (this is also shared with Remote Desktop) Ctrl+Alt+Break/Pause : will toggle between full-screen and windowed. As you mention, Ctrl+Alt+Del is less useful in Windows Sandbox, but triggering the Start menu and Alt+Tab functionality are quite valuable to me as I'm in the container quite a lot at the moment testing various large IBM apps for work so I'll be using those key-combos you found quite a bit.  I always remembered the Ctrl+Alt+End one from years of using Remote Desktop and it's quite odd that it does not work here, yes.